# Uninstall Adblock Extension from Chrome completly

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, uninstall, adblock

I have already uninstalled Adblock from chrome extension.
But I keep seeing console logs of Adblock blocking certain urls. And if I visit certain website they keep showing me overlay of "Please uninstall Adblocker" even though I have already removed it. Im using MAC os Chrome 64bit.

[image: adblocker console log]

Answer (score 1):

From what I have observed from your screenshot , you are logged in to the Chrome. So , even if you have removed the adblock , I suspect that it's being reinstalled from the synced data in your Google account.

Here are the few suggestions provided by adblocker site: [Link](https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000101717-adblock-keeps-coming-back-after-i-uninstall-it-)

Hope this solves it.

Comment: I did reset my chrome sync now but did not resolve. Im afraid I cant remove my chrome account it has many important data.

Comment: Thats the thing we have. Even if you reset your sync data for now, it will be okay for this iteration. But when it re sync s data, it will appear again. Only option is to signout from Chrome account or to delete adblocker and create new account after that!